# how to do firebase-authentication with next.js

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, next.js

I am getting so much problem in creating a next.js app with express and firebase-authentication and what is the use of redux here.can anyone Please Help in this stuff or provide some tutorials because next.js documentation is not worthy and examples are too not worthy.

Answer (score 0):

#### The example `with-firebase-authentication` in the NextJs examples folder is not working right now:

See my bug report: [with-firebase-example-not-working](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/10025)

I'm trying to do this using service-workers since it's supported by Firebase:
[firebase-docs-to-service-workers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/service-worker-sessions)

I've been looking at a NextJS example with service-workers:
[nextjs-example-with-sw](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/85769c3d3296cdcddc0fb36f05058c8e451ca57f/examples/with-sw-precache)
But I found that the `sw-precache webpack plugin` is deprecated by Google and they recommend to migrate to the `sw-toolbox` see here: [google-sw-toolbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-sw)

But have in mind that this adds an overhead of sw configuration and registering/un-registering  as well as the scope on the sw in your app.

To learn more about service workers check [google-dev-docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers)

Comment: It is working. See also the bug report you mentioned.

Comment: Yep @Roy thanks seem like it was an issue with my npm modules